# How to get DOMAIN name from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, domain-name, ssms-2005

I tried using `EXEC sp_who2;` to find the server's domain name, but it gives host, users, etc.

I need to know my SQL Server's **domain name**, so I can install a plugin to the SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In T-SQL, you would use this to query the Domain Name of the SQL Server:

```
SELECT DEFAULT_DOMAIN()[DomainName]
```

Comment: If the server is running on a non-domain-member system this gives the workgroup name. How can you tell if the return value is really a domain name and not a workgroup name?

Answer (score 10):

Get your FQDN like so:

```
DECLARE @Domain varchar(100)

EXEC master..xp_regread
     @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
    ,@key = 'SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\'
    ,@value_name = 'Domain'
    ,@value = @Domain OUTPUT

SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS [@@SERVERNAME]
    ,@Domain AS [@Domain]
```

Comment: access denied.  bummer.